# Delete child objects in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-relationship

I'm using EF and when I do this:

```
            foreach (var reg in detail.Regs)
            {
                this.db.Regs.DeleteObject(reg);
            }
```

I get this:

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

What I'm I doing wrong here???

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The reason for that is because as you delete the objects from the context, EF is actively update the *Regs* navigation property count which means the *detail.Regs* collection is being changed during the *foreach* loop which always cause the exception you are getting.

You can create a new collection object and keep deleting from it like this:

```
foreach (var reg in detail.Regs.ToList())
{
    this.db.Regs.DeleteObject(reg);
}
```

Or even you can make it cleaner by using LINQ *ForEach* method:

```
detail.Regs.ToList().ForEach(r => db.Regs.DeleteObject(r));
```

Comment: That get all the records from the database just to have them deleted no?