# Deleting principal and dependents for independent association (one-to-many)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework 6 with the **Designer**, all our entities have an *[independent association](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx)*. So no foreign keys are defined in our model's properties.

Having the following entities with a one-to-many relationship:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
public class Child
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping to the following SQL tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Parent (
    Id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Parent PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
)

CREATE TABLE Child (
    Id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    FkParent uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Child PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
)

ALTER TABLE Child WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Child_Parent FOREIGN KEY(FkParent) REFERENCES Parent ([Id])

ALTER TABLE Child CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_Child_Parent
```

As you can see we are not using `CASCADE ON DELETE`, because my team is against the usage of it.

So the question is, what's the correct way to delete a parent and it's dependent children given only the parent's `Id`?
With *delete*, I mean that the SQL records in both tables should be deleted (resulting in a `DELETE` SQL statement) after calling `.SaveChanges()`.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a database [trigger](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_triggers.htm) on the delete command on the but I dislike 'hiding' functionality in triggers and that would be just like the Cascade on delete functionality. Maybe just build it into the business logic of your (repository?) delete handler.

Comment: @JaredStroeb, exactly. Me and my team also don't like these kinds of database functionalities which ultimately hides them from business logic in the application. However, this discussion has a tendency towards design choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only way I figured out how to achieve this, is by *explicitly* loading the children into memory and deleting them one by one before actually deleting the parent.

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var parent = context.Parents.Find(parentId);
    //or use LINQ if you prefer:
    var alternative = context.Parents.Single(p => p.Id == parentId)

    foreach(var child in parent.Children.ToList())
    {
        context.Children.Remove(child);
    }

    context.Parents.Remove(parent);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Note the `.ToList()` (or `.ToArray()` if you prefer) on the `Children` which is **important**, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150781/delete-child-objects-in-entity-framework).

Performance-wise this is not ideal, because you have to query every child record from the database and load this into memory (I suppose for a small application, this wouldn't matter though). But I couldn't find a better approach without using `CASCADE ON DELETE`, even though I'm not sure if that would really outperform this case.